# when to use endSession with node.js and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB to write web applications, and I'd like to use transactions. I've studied the documentation examples like this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/master/fundamentals/transactions/#std-label-nodejs-transaction-core-api-example

The misunderstanding I have is when to use the `endSession` method. In the "bank account" example I have below, I have a function that transfers an amount from one account to another using `withTransaction` function. It works fine, unless it ends the session that it starts. If I include the `endSession` method call, I get an error, not there, but at the next database operation, namely looking up an account. The error is `MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended`

Here's the complete code for the bank account example:

```
const path = require('path');
require("dotenv").config({ path: path.join(process.env.HOME, '.cs304env')});
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const mongoUser = process.env.MONGO_USERNAME;
const mongoPass = process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD;
const mongoUri = `mongodb+srv://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@cluster0.dn6vs.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

const conn = new MongoClient(mongoUri,
                             { useNewUrlParser: true,
                               useUnifiedTopology: true
                             });

const DB = 'scottdb';
const ACCOUNTS = 'accounts';

const ALICE = {name: "Alice", balance: 20};
const BETTY = {name: "Betty", balance: 20};
const CATHY = {name: "Cathy", balance: 20};

async function init(db) { 
    await db.collection(ACCOUNTS).deleteMany({});
    await db.collection(ACCOUNTS).insertMany([ALICE, BETTY, CATHY]);
}

async function transfer(db, acctFrom, acctTo, amount) {
    let col = db.collection(ACCOUNTS);
    await col.updateOne({name: acctFrom}, {$inc: {balance: -1*amount}});
    await col.updateOne({name: acctTo}, {$inc: {balance: +1*amount}});
}

async function transferAtomic(conn, db, acctFrom, acctTo, amount) {
    // conn = await Connection.open(mongoUri);
    // db = conn.db(DB);
    const session = conn.startSession();
    let col = db.collection(ACCOUNTS);
    await session.withTransaction( async () => {
        console.log('sub');
        await col.updateOne({name: acctFrom}, {$inc: {balance: -1*amount}}, {session});
        await col.updateOne({name: acctTo}, {$inc: {balance: +1*amount}}, {session});
    });
    session.commitTransaction(); 
    session.endSession();     // **omitting this avoids the problem**
}

async function getAccount(db, name) {
    console.log('lookup', name);
    let result = await db.collection(ACCOUNTS).find({name: name}).toArray();
    if( result.length == 0 ) return null;
    console.log('result', result[0])
}

async function main() {
    await conn.connect();
    const db = conn.db(DB);
    await init(db);
    await transferAtomic(conn, db, "Alice", "Betty", 5);
    await transferAtomic(conn, db, "Alice", "Cathy", 3);
    await getAccount(db, "Alice");
    await getAccount(db, "Betty");
    await getAccount(db, "Cathy");
    await conn.close();
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

I've marked the problematic line. I was expecting a symmetry between starting a session and ending a session. But the code works if I start sessions and never end them.

I'm confused because when I omit that line, the code works, but the resulting program starts two sessions and ends none. Do sessions just accumulate forever until the application exits? If not, what is the proper time to end them, and how is that done correctly? All of the examples and documentation does the `endSession` when the program exits, but that doesn't make sense for a long-running web application.

Thanks for your help!

Scott